# GetElementbyId from XMLHttpRequest() in IE 8.0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, youtube-javascript-api

i am developing youtube user history view functionality, now  here i am trying to get YouTube userId  using youtubeInfoUri and requested token,

here this code is working awesome in FF and Chrome, but fail in IE

```
function getDataFromXML() {
try {

    youTubeUserInfoUri += acToken; // global variable currently. 
    // i.e youTubeUserInfoUri = "https://gdata...."
    //IE : if URI contain https  then exception thrown  :
    /* description : $lineinfo is undefined */
    /* Name : TypeeEror */        

    //To handle this :
    youTubeUserInfoUri = youTubeUserInfoUri.replace("https", "http");

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", youTubeUserInfoUri, false);


    request.timeout = 3000;
    request.onprogress = function () { };
    request.ontimeout = function () { };
    request.onerror = function () { };


    request.send();

    if (request.status == 200) {

        var xml = request.responseXML;
```

here in xml : i got childnodes = {count 0}; item =invalid number of parameters

Now I m totally blank here , dont have any idea why this happend..

```
        if (xml == null) {
            //if Google account dont have youtube account / error 401 found ,
            showShortNotification("YouTube", "current user is not linked with YouTube", "error");
        } else {

            //Browser exception handle :  
            //TagName understanding is different by FF and & Chrome browser,

            var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("username"); // here check for Chrome:   Firefox will not understand this tag name
            if (users.length == 0) { // if its length is 0 means no elements found, so try for next tag method
                users = xml.getElementsByTagName("yt:username"); // here firefox understand this method


          /* In IE : during debug point : here users = Item : Invalid number of parameters.*/


            }

            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var youtubeUserid = (users[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                YoutubeUserHistoryFetch(youtubeUserid);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert("Error found" + e);

   }
 }
```

I also tried 
[1]   new window.XDomainRequest();
[2]   try changing Internet Explorer Trusted Site Zones settings (Internet Explorer Options->Security-> Trusted Sites  + Custom Level , scroll down and change Access data sources across domains value to Enable

Xml Response Text  :

```
 .....<yt:maxUploadDuration seconds="930" /> 
 <yt:statistics lastWebAccess="1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" subscriberCount="9" videoWatchCount="0" viewCount="0" totalUploadViews="70" /> 
  <media:thumbnail url="http://yt4.ggpht.com/-pFKkUesgV-Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/I23mZGfUo-A/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg" /> 
  <yt:username>saun4frsh</yt:username>
```

I need

Please help, if you have any idea to solve this.
Only problem with Internet Explorer ,  Same code working fine in Chrome and FF.

I have IE8, and win 7 OS.

Comment: Do not use synchronous requests.

Comment: If I used >>  request.open("GET", youTubeUserInfoUri); instead of request.open("GET", youTubeUserInfoUri,false)   I got Error  ::: responseText="The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Code : Specially For IE 8 , 100% working

```
function getDataFromXML() {
try {
    youTubeUserInfoUri += acToken;
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
        var rssData = httpGet();
        var youtubeUserid = convertToArrayForIE(rssData.getElementsByTagName('yt:username'));
        YoutubeUserHistoryFetch(youtubeUserid[0]);

    } else {
    //Rest ur code for FF/Chrome Old code
  }
}
catch{}
}

function httpGet() {

youTubeUserInfoUri = youTubeUserInfoUri.replace("https", "http"); //IE not allows https : security issue.
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', youTubeUserInfoUri, false);
xmlHttp.send();

if (window.DOMParser) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, 'text/xml');
    return doc;
}
else {
    var xmlDocument = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    xmlDocument.async = false;
    xmlDocument.loadXML(xmlHttp.responseText);
    return xmlDocument;
   }
}

function convertToArrayForIE(htmlCollection) {
var nodes = [];
var collectionLength = htmlCollection.length;
for (var i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++) {
    nodes.push(htmlCollection.item(i).firstChild.text);
}
return nodes;
}
```